# Move projectile to mouse-click position AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript

I have a cannon and cannonball. How do I make a cannonball to move in a line from cannon to the Mouse Click position and stop/disappear/activate Explode animation?

I've tried different solutions and none of them would seem to work for me so I cleared it a bit.

And yes, I know it's ugly.

```html
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.Sprite;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFr);

function enterFr(e:Event)
{
 aims.x = mouseX;
 aims.y = mouseY;
}

Mouse.hide();

zamok.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire);

function fire(m:MouseEvent)
{
 var s:Sound = new cannonFire();
 s.play();
 var explo:boom = new boom();
 explo.x = mouseX;
 explo.y = mouseY;
 addChild(explo);
}
```

Comment: Show us some code as to what you have already tried. Last I checked, SO is for seeking help and advice, and not for generating ready-to-use code :)

Comment: @GurtejSingh you would hate me if I show it to you, seriously, I better not do it, it's too ugly and oh well...

Comment: Your code looks fine btw. You can probably use a Tween to animate the cannon to the mouseX and mouseY position and on completion of the tween have it explode. I usually use Tweenlite for all my animations, but that's a third party, so if you're cool with it, give it a shot. It's pretty easy. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Well you should think of the process that you want to implement. 
First of all it is not instant, it takes some time for cannonball to move to the point where mouse clicked. 
Let's start with some function that will create a cannonball:

```
private function fireCannonBall(target: Point):void 
{
    const cannonBall:CannonBall = new CannonBall(); // you need to implement this class, or just use some MovieClip from library;

    cannonBall.x = initialPosition.x; // initial position is a point where your cannon is located.
    cannonBall.y = initialPosition.y; 

    addChild(cannonBall);

    // I suggest using TweenNano, but it has some limitations, read the License Agreement carefully
    TweenNano.to(cannonBall, 15 /* animation duration */, {x: target.x, y: target.y, onComplete: makeExplosion, onCompleteParams: [cannonBall]});
}

private function makeExplosion(cannonBall: CannonBall):void 
{
    /* I leave this part to you, here you might want to launch some explosion animation */
}
```

Now we need to handle the click:

```
private function onMouseClick(e: MouseEvent):void 
{
    const target: Point = new Point(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    //and launch the cannonBall:
    fireCannonBall(target);
}
```

That's it, roughly.

To know more about TweenNano please follow the link: 
https://greensock.com/tweennano-as